# How to classify a 3D "Knapsack" problem where the only limitation is space, i.e. there is no weight constraint?

Tags: optimization, packing

The problem is defined as: pack a 3D space with a given list of 3 types of cuboids which are each assigned a value, trying to either completely fill the space or to achieve the highest total value of the packing. 
When researching knapsack problems all of the different variations I came across
had a weight constraint and most didn't consider geometrical 3D space as a constraint. So my question is: is my problem considered a knapsack problem and/or is there a different term for these kind of problems which I could look into further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [standard Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) (solvable by DP) when we are packing objects we do not care about how we put objects in the knapsack, i.e., what only matters is a subset of objects and the sum of weights of these objects. But, in cuboid/rectangle packing problem the configuration of the cubes/rectangle is important to achieve the optimal packing. So, from this point of view these problems are different. I googled and found [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f691/7488ff3947ed5736727a15f40dd8d19cb2e9.pdf) heuristic approach and [this](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~rharren/publications/Harren-StudentResearchPaper.pdf) article.